# How would I create a new object in a field that is a sortedmap?

Tags: java, tree, field, sortedmap

Field children is a SortedMap. SortedMap is an interface. So to create an new object to store in field children, you need to use some class that implements SortedMap. We suggest using class java.util.TreeMap.

And while using this:

```
private SortedMap<Move,State> children= null;
```

How would I go about this? I really don't want anyone doing my assignment for me, so I'm not going to post the code so I hope you guys can help with the little I can post.

Would it be something like:

```
SortedMap <Move, State> children = new SortedMap <Move, State>;
```

but I keep getting an error.

Comment: *"We suggest using class java.util.TreeMap."* Have you tried that?

Comment: @Radiodef yes but I wasn't sure how to, would it be SortedMap <Move, State> children = new TreeMap();??

Comment: Exactly: SortedMap <Move, State> children = new TreeMap<Move, State>();

Comment: @RomanŁomowski or, easier, `SortedMap<Move, State> children = new TreeMap<>();` (assuming Java 7+).

Comment: @user5970051: What Andy suggested is a shorter form of the same statement. You don't have to provide generics for TreeMap (in this statement) as they can be found out from the context - they have to be the same as those of SortedMap.